# Simple bash script won't execute but identical scripts will

Tags: linux, bash

I have a simple bash script (test) which wont run.

The file is in a folder I've directed PATH to.

Neither:

```
$ test
```

nor:

```
$ ./test
```

execute the command.

The script is designated as executable (chmod +x test).

I've tried copying the script into another executable and it runs fine.

I've tried removing "test" and remaking it and it still fails.

I've tried removing then reapplying the executable designation and it still fails.

This is not a huge problem as I can just use a different file name but it's very frustrating.

Code is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

VAR=$1
echo $VAR
```

What I expect to see:

```
$ test hi
hi
$
```

What I see:

```
$ test hi
$
```

What I see when I copy the script:

```
$ cp test test1
$ chmod +x test1
$ test1 hi
hi
$
```

To summarize, my workspace looks like:

```
$ test hi
$ cp test test1
$ chmod +x test1
$ test1 hi
hi
$
```

Comment: I would suggest to not name this `test` since this can be a system executable or a build-in...`$ which test` for me yields `/bin/test`. In any case tho `./test` should have worked. Without `./` you are running systems' test and not your script

Comment: `test` is a built-in command in the shell. Call your script something else, or use `./test` to unambiguously run the script in the current directory.

Answer (score 2):

`test` is likely to be a shell builtin or a binary.
Do this to see what it is: `type test`.

So whenever you execute the command test, either the shell builtin, or the binary (usually `/usr/bin/test`) will execute.

If you want your own test to execute, call it explicitly, like so: `./test`.